# select query between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2008

I am trying tomake a select join between two specific dates in the database

This I feelis on the right path but is incorrect

How can I get this to work

```
SELECT --RTRIM(C.CustomerFirstName) + ' ' + LTRIM(C.CustomerLastName) as CustomerFullName,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CP.ActionDate) AS RowNumber,
       C.CustomerFirstName,
       C.CustomerLastName,
       C.CustomerCompany,
       C.CustomerPosition,
       C.CustomerCountry,
       C.CustomerProvince,
       C.CustomerContact,
       CP.ActionDate,
       CP.ProductCode,
       CP.CustomerEmail
FROM   tblCustomers C
       JOIN tblCustomerProducts CP
            ON  C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail


     ORDER BY ActionDate DESC
WHERE CP.ActionDate BETWEEN '1/17/2013' AND '19/12/2012'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
WHERE CP.ActionDate BETWEEN '1/17/2013' AND '19/12/2012`
```

Try this:

```
WHERE CP.ActionDate BETWEEN '19/12/2012' AND '1/17/2013'
```

**Note that:** This is because the `BETWEEN` predicate in SQL Server is **Asymmetric**, this means that `value1 BETWEEN value2 AND value3` is the same as `Value1 >= Value2 AND Value1 <= Value3`, so the value `value2` that before the `AND` must be less than or equal to the `value3`.

Answer (score 4):

The smaller date has to be listed first

```
BETWEEN '12/19/2012'  AND '1/17/2013'
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your current query.

First, you have the dates in the wrong order.

Second, you have the `ORDER BY` in the wrong place. The `ORDER BY` is the last item listed in your select:

```
FROM tblCustomers C
JOIN tblCustomerProducts CP 
   ON C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail
WHERE CP.ActionDate BETWEEN  '12/19/2012' AND '1/17/2013'
ORDER BY ActionDate DESC
```

You can also use:

```
FROM tblCustomers C
JOIN tblCustomerProducts CP 
   ON C.CustomerEmail = CP.CustomerEmail
WHERE CP.ActionDate >= '12/19/2012' AND CP.ActionDate <= '1/17/2013'
ORDER BY ActionDate DESC
```

I would also advise that you be sure that the dates are formatted in the same manner. You have one as `DD/MM/YYYY` and the other as `MM/DD/YYYY`

Answer (score 2):

You misplaced dates, it should be smaller one at first place and larger one at second place:

```
WHERE CP.ActionDate BETWEEN '19/12/2012' AND '1/17/2013'
```

OR

```
WHERE CP.ActionDate >= '19/12/2012' AND CP.ActionDate <= '1/17/2013'
```